# Docker run throws error when user namespaces are used with SELinux on

Tags: docker, selinux, linux-namespaces

I am trying to get Docker user namespaces to work with SELinux enabled on Centos 7.5. However, I get this error everytime:

```
docker run -itd --name temp -p 80:80 httpd

1a83588651b407e547881e15190b6d39692a7a2cf2df73dcaf4f37730ebdca65
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:301: running exec setns process for init caused \"exit status 40\"": unknown.
```

This does not happen if I turn of SELinux.

Here is my /etc/docker/daemon.json:

```
{
"userns-remap": "dockerspace",
"hosts": ["unix:///var/run/docker.sock", "tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"],
"tls": true,
"tlscacert": "/etc/pki/tls/certs/docker-ca.pem",
"tlscert": "/etc/pki/tls/certs/docker-cert.pem",
"tlskey": "/etc/pki/tls/private/docker-key.pem",
"tlsverify": true,
"selinux-enabled": true
}
```

uname -a output:

```
Linux atlantis.newtarget.net 3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jul 16 16:29:36 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

cat /proc/cmdline output:

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/centos-root ro crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=centos/root rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap rhgb quiet LANG=en_US.UTF-8 namespace.unpriv_enable=1 user_namespace.enable=1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a bit more going on than I do when I was getting that error, but here goes!

Based on your cat /proc/cmdline output it looks like you have already done:

`sudo grubby --args="namespace.unpriv_enable=1" --update-kernel=/boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r)`
You might need to restart for this to take effect (if you haven't already).

You also need to make sure the value in */proc/sys/user/max_user_namespaces* is at least greater than 0:

`echo 12345 > /proc/sys/user/max_user_namespaces`

These settings along with configuring [*/etc/subuid, /etc/subgid, /etc/docker/daemon.json*] correctly it worked for me with selinux enabled. [docker documentation on user namespacing, how to configure the above files (must be done manually for each on centos/rhel)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/#prerequisites)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions. However, I tried all the options you suggested before posting here (grub updates, max_user_namespaces, subuid,gid, etc) :-(